# Starting Appium programmatically - Connection Refused

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I want to automate the testing of a mobile app using the android emulator.
I am trying to start Appium programmatically and then pass its IP and Port into Webdriver, to be used.

Before I pass it to the Webdriver, I print out the Appium Service's IP/Port it is running on, and it is 0.0.0.0:4723, but I am getting a Connection Refused after passing it to Webdriver.

If I manually start Appium, it is starting on 0.0.0.0:4723, just fine.

Please find my code and StackTrace below.

```
public class AppiumServerJava {

public AppiumDriverLocalService service;
public AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
public DesiredCapabilities cap;
public WebDriver driver = null;
public DesiredCapabilities dc;

File root = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File app = new File(root, "/src/test/api/app-qa.apk");

public WebDriver startServer() {

    // apk Capabilities
    dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.ANDROID);
    dc.setCapability("deviceName", "nexus5");
    dc.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.aa.android.qa");
    dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.aa.android.view.SplashActivity");

    // Appium Capabilities
    cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

    // Build the Appium Service
    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("/home/ninad/.linuxbrew/bin/node"));
    builder.withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/bin/appium"));
    builder.withIPAddress("0.0.0.0");
    builder.usingPort(4723);
    builder.withCapabilities(cap);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error");

    // Start the server with the builder
    try {
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    String appiumServiceUrl = service.getUrl().toString();
    System.out.println("Appium URL " + appiumServiceUrl);

    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(appiumServiceUrl), dc);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return driver;
}


public void stopServer() {
    service.stop();
}

public boolean checkIfServerIsRunnning(int port) {

    boolean isServerRunning = false;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // If control comes here, then it means that the port is in use
        isServerRunning = true;
    } finally {
        serverSocket = null;
    }
    return isServerRunning;
}
}


AppiumServerJava appiumServer = new AppiumServerJava();
public static WebDriver driver = null;


@Before("@setup")
public void setUp() {

    int port = 4723;
    try {
        if (!appiumServer.checkIfServerIsRunnning(port)) {
            appiumServer.startServer();
            appiumServer.stopServer();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Appium Server already running on Port - " + port);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver = appiumServer.startServer();
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.destroyProcess(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:175)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.start(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:138)
    at Utilities.AppiumServerJava.startServer(AppiumServerJava.java:57)
    at mobileTest.appiumSeleniumCucumberAndroid.StepDefinitions.setUp(StepDefinitions.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)Appium URL http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub

    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Failure in before hook:StepDefinitions.setUp()
Message: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'
System info: host: 'ninad-Gazelle', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-42-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$2(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:101)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:254)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:87)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:111)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:72)
    at Utilities.AppiumServerJava.startServer(AppiumServerJava.java:66)
    at mobileTest.appiumSeleniumCucumberAndroid.StepDefinitions.setUp(StepDefinitions.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:337)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
    ... 29 more

      org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
      Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'
      System info: host: 'ninad-Gazelle', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-42-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
      Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$2(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:101)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:100)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:254)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:87)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:111)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:72)
        at Utilities.AppiumServerJava.startServer(AppiumServerJava.java:66)
        at mobileTest.appiumSeleniumCucumberAndroid.StepDefinitions.setUp(StepDefinitions.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
      Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:139)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:87)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:337)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
        ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I have remove the port details and replaced with usingAnyPort, below is the sample junit test which worked for me

```
public class AppiumServerJava {

private AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;


@Before
public void startAppiumServer() {
    startServer();
}

@Test
public void serviceStartTest() {
    System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView")).size());
}

@After
public void teardown() {
    driver.quit();
}

public void startServer() {


    AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
    DesiredCapabilities cap;
    DesiredCapabilities dc;

    File app = new File("/Users/test/Desktop/APK/staging.apk");
    // apk Capabilities
    dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.ANDROID);
    dc.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
    dc.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    // Appium Capabilities
    cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

    // Build the Appium Service
    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/bin/appium"));
    builder.withIPAddress("0.0.0.0");
    builder.usingAnyFreePort();
    builder.withCapabilities(cap);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error");

    // Start the server with the builder
    AppiumDriverLocalService service = null;
    try {
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String appiumServiceUrl = service.getUrl().toString();
    System.out.println("Appium URL " + appiumServiceUrl);

    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(appiumServiceUrl), dc);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

'

Comment: thank you so much JC.
this solution worked for me after trying so many different things.

Answer (score 1):

**Start your appium Server with below informaiton**

host : 127.0.0.1
Port: 4890

**and use below URL in the script**

URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4890/wd/hub");